# Why my log4j slf4j log once only when tomcat initialize war file?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, slf4j, cas

My environment:
CAS 4.0.0 project
dependencies
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5
log4j-1.2.17
slf4j-api.1.7.5

(Whole process in remote debug) when the tomcat initialize the webapp, in DatasourceWrapper, logger does log(i checked). But the problem is the logger does not log after webapp initialized.

My java file

```
package sg.com.innovax;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DatasourceWrapper extends BasicDataSource implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4139847655780946796L;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException 
    {


            logger.debug("Number of active connections:" + super.getNumActive());
            logger.info("Number of idle connections:" + super.getNumIdle());
            logger.error("Number of max active:" + super.getMaxActive());

        return super.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException 
    {

            logger.debug("Number of active connections:" + super.getNumActive());
            logger.info("Number of idle connections:" + super.getNumIdle());
            logger.error("Number of max active:" + super.getMaxActive());

        return super.getConnection(username, password);
    }
}
```

my xml

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <!--
      This default ConsoleAppender is used to logger all NON perf4j messages
      to System.out
    -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="cas" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="cas123.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="512KB" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Perf4J appenders -->
    <!--
       This AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender groups StopWatch logger messages
       into GroupedTimingStatistics messages which it sends on the
       file appender defined below
    -->
    <appender name="CoalescingStatistics" class="org.perf4j.log4j.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="60000"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="graphExecutionTimes"/>
        <appender-ref ref="graphExecutionTPS"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- This file appender is used to output aggregated performance statistics -->
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="perfStats.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="graphExecutionTimes" class="org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
        <!-- Possible GraphTypes are Mean, Min, Max, StdDev, Count and TPS -->
        <param name="GraphType" value="Mean"/>
        <!-- The tags of the timed execution blocks to graph are specified here -->
        <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="DESTROY_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET,GRANT_SERVICE_TICKET,GRANT_PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET,VALIDATE_SERVICE_TICKET,CREATE_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET,AUTHENTICATE" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="graphExecutionTPS" class="org.perf4j.log4j.GraphingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="GraphType" value="TPS" />
        <param name="TagNamesToGraph" value="DESTROY_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET,GRANT_SERVICE_TICKET,GRANT_PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET,VALIDATE_SERVICE_TICKET,CREATE_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET,AUTHENTICATE" />
    </appender>

    <!-- Loggers -->
    <!--
      The Perf4J logger. Note that org.perf4j.TimingLogger is the value of the
      org.perf4j.StopWatch.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME constant. Also, note that
      additivity is set to false, which is usually what is desired - this means
      that timing statements will only be sent to this logger and NOT to
      upstream loggers.
    -->
    <logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CoalescingStatistics" />
    </logger>

    <!--
        WARNING: Setting the org.springframework logger to DEBUG displays debug information about
        the request parameter values being bound to the command objects.  This could expose your
        password in the logger file.  If you are sharing your logger files, it is recommend you selectively
        apply DEBUG level logging on a an org.springframework.* package level (i.e. org.springframework.dao)
    -->
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.webflow">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.jasig" additivity="true">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="cas" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="cas" />
    </logger>

    <!--
        WARNING: Setting the flow package to DEBUG will display
        the parameters posted to the login servlet including
        cleartext authentication credentials
    -->
    <logger name="org.jasig.cas.web.flow" additivity="true">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="cas" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="sg.com.innovax">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="cas" />
    </logger>
    <!--
      The root logger sends all logger statements EXCEPT those sent to the perf4j
      logger to System.out.
    -->
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

another xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <description>
        Log4J initialization.  Configuration options are sourced from cas.properties.  This allows deployers to externalize
        both cas.properties and log4j.xml, so that a single cas.war file can be deployed to multiple tiers or hosts without
        having to do any post configuration.  This approach helps to preserve configuration between upgrades.

        Deployers should not have to edit this file.
    </description>

    <bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
        p:targetClass="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" p:targetMethod="initLogging" p:arguments-ref="arguments"/>

    <util:list id="arguments">
       <value>${log4j.config.location:classpath:log4j.xml}</value>
       <value>${log4j.refresh.interval:60000}</value>
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

My datasourceWrapper in sg.com.innovax, and i do specify in log4j

```
<logger name="sg.com.innovax">
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="cas" />
        </logger>
```

then it should be able to log in cas.log, however when i check from netbeans output, it show the error info in apache tomcat.

Comment: i guess it's about your logging section. Are you sure DatasourceWrapper is being called after the initialize ?

Comment: yes, i purposely did it

Comment: Are you checking perfStats.log or catalina.out ? Please check both